# How insert register if not exist - trigger mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a list of records that I have to insert, but I do not want duplicates to be inserted with the same fields, I need to verify if this record exists and do not insert it and continue to analyze the following

```
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Leads WHERE n_documento = new.n_documento AND programa = new.programa) THEN
    INSERT INTO Leads
    VALUES
    (NULL, new.nombres, new.apellidos, new.n_documento, new.fecha_de_nacimiento, new.telefono, new.email, new.ciudad, 
    new.pais, new.anos_de_experiencia, new.origen, new.informacion_adicional, new.fecha, new.programa, new.estado, new.fecha_charla,
    new.grado_de_estudio, new.empresa, new.cargo, null);
END IF;
```

my trigger does not work, it does not validate and it allows entering the duplicates

Comment: Can you add the delimiter setting and the rest of the trigger please.

Comment: Is this a one off thing, or an on going check you want to perform for every insert?

Answer (score 0):

Handling this in a trigger is not the best or most efficient place to handle this.

What you could do is build a compound unique index.   Which would then in turn NOT allow you to insert a second row where the selected column values match identically to another row.

eg.

```
ALTER TABLE `YourSchema`.`YourTableName` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `CompoundUniqueIndexName` (`Col1` ASC, `Col2` ASC, `Col3` ASC);
```

Now running the following one time:

```
INSERT INTO `YourSchema`.`YourTableName` (`Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`) VALUES ('Bob', 'Jim', 'Bill');
```

Will successfully add a row.  But you run it a second time, and you will get the following error and the row will not be insert:

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'Bob-Jim-Bill' for key
>   'CompoundUniqueIndexName'

**Caveat**

I have found Every value in your compound index needs to have a value.  So it is important to set each column involved in your compound index to be NOT NULL.  Additionally it may be in your interest to also supply a default value like '0' or something if you can not control the input to assure a value is present.

The reason for this is I'm not entirely sure of,  But I know the following two statements will NOT produce a 'Duplicate Entry' error, because Col3 will be NULL without the above precautions.

```
INSERT INTO `YourSchema`.`YourTableName` (`Col1`, `Col2`) VALUES ('Bob', 'Jim');
```

Then again,

```
INSERT INTO `YourSchema`.`YourTableName` (`Col1`, `Col2`) VALUES ('Bob', 'Jim');
```

Answer (score -1):

This type of condition may be more performance if you use it in queries.

SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Leads

Comment: mysql equivalent of top is limit.But I don't see how this would help.